# Dynamically import every module in a given directory/package

Tags: python, import, importerror

I have a file structure like this:

```
dir_a
    __init__.py
    mod_1.py
    mod_2.py
dir_b
    __init__.py
    my_mod.py
```

I want to dynamically import every module in `dir_a` in `my_mod.py`, and in order to do that, I have the following inside the `__init__.py` of `dir_a`:

```
import os
import glob
__all__ = [os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/*.py")]
```

But when I do:

```
from dir_a import *
```

I get `ImportError: No module named dir_a`

I wonder what causes this, is it because the parent directory containing `dir_a` and `dir_b` has to be in PYTHONPATH? In addition, the above approach is dynamic only in the sense that `my_mod.py` picks up everything when it is run, but if a new module is added to `dir_a` during its run this new module won't be picked up. So is it possible to implement a truly dynamic importing mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is a trivial yes: you cannot `import dir_a` when the directory containing `dir_a` isn't in the search path.

For the second part, I don't believe that is possible in general - you *could* listen for 'file created' OS signals in `dir_a`, see whether the created file is a `.py`, and add it to `dir_a.__all__` - but that is complicated, probably expensive, and doesn't retroactively add the new thing to the global namespace, since `from foo import *` only sees what is in `foo.__all__` at import time. And changing *that* would be error-prone - it allows your namespace to change at any time based on an unpredictable external event. Say you do this:

```
from dir_a import *
bar = 5
```

And then a `bar.py` gets added to `dir_a`. You can't write a "truly dynamic importer" without considering that situation, and deciding what you want to have happen.